# unable to obtain refresh token spotify api

Tags: oauth, spotify

I want to refresh my spotify oAuth tokens but my request fails and i dont get any error message

i am currently developing a react native app using supabase. I am able to sign in using the pkce flow, but i am now stuck at refreshing the spotify token.

I am receiving an error response but sadly without any further information

```
{"error": "invalid_request", "error_description": ""}
```

this is my current implementation:

```
class SpotifyTokenRefreshStrategy implements TokenRefreshStrategy {

async refreshTokens(config: RefreshTokenConfig): Promise<void> {

const url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

const clientId: string | undefined =

process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID

if (!clientId) {

throw new Error("Spotify client ID not found")

 }

const data = {

grant_type: "refresh_token",

refresh_token: config.refreshToken,

client_id: clientId,

 }

const body = Object.entries(data)

 .map(

 ([key, value]) =>

`${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`

 )

 .join("&")

const payload = {

method: "POST",

headers: {

"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

 },

body: body,

 }

try {

const response = await fetch(url, payload)

console.log("response", await response.json())

if (!response.ok) {

throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`)

 }

const json = await response.json()

console.log("Spotify refresh response:", json)

 } catch (error) {

console.error("Error:", error)

throw error

 }

 }

}
```

the client_id is defined, as well as the refresh token. I can be sure of that because when i remove or modify those parameters from the request, the error message changes to invalid client_id/refresh_token. So it seems that those two paramters are correct, but there is still an issue in the code.

the body strings looks like this:

```
grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=AQBtIQoY8tim8s5LMjkgSZBF3lxqdOH_NBL40Ha-VvhRDPb_B04hlwe7s6sw_UPZrGwrwIXmJodBehxeiqZLAqAI4SvJBW54OoP_ooVNmnt704bwCrTQybKtRpFybLq9DN0&client_id=3f122ae12969427e9807f76a43ce6350
```

i also have added all available scopes, because i thought maybe this is the cause of the error but it isnt.

I am really really stuck on this, so i would appreciate any help from y'all :)

Comment: What is the response code? That will give you a good hint as to the nature of the problem.

Comment: the response code is 400

Comment: A bad request means the server doesn't understand what you're sending. That suggests that the message headers and/or body are problematic. If you're confident it's interpreting the body correctly, the refresh token itself may be bad (though that would normally return a 403.) Outside of `Content-Type`, what else does their API specify has to be in the headers? Do they require an `Accept` header?

Comment: Looking at [their documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/access-token), it appears they expect the authorization to be in the headers, not the body of the request.

Comment: form what i understand from the docs is that the pkce flow does not require an Auth in the header: 

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/refreshing-tokens

Comment: i did exactly that and am now at a point where i addressed any error messages. Now i am stuck here with no further explanation why this isnt working

Comment: Oh #duh! Sorry.

Comment: I've had similar issues diagnosing this kind of thing by using the native error object. Try using `response.text()` instead of `response.json()` where you're logging the response.

Comment: i get the same object then, just not in JSON syntax. So sadly no new information

Comment: Blerg. You might try changing how you specify the body such that you're using their URLSearchParams approach. 

```body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        client_id: clientId,
      }),```
I wouldn't be shocked if it produced slightly different results than the manual approach you've adopted here.